# Getting an idea to prove the equality of mixed partial derivatives $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I was reading the partial differentiation unit today and came across this theorem. I read this before but never focused towards the proof. Now while seeing the proof, I am thinking how would one get the idea to prove the theorem by considering different functions and using mean value theorem four times.

I am referring Thomas calculus eleventh edition. The book gives a proof in the appendix. (I gave the text book name to be more informative)

My question is as said above "How can one get an idea to prove the theorem".

It would also be helpful if somebody point out some link about how the proof was done by the man who actually proved it.

Comment: What theorem? It is not there.

Comment: equality of mixed partial derivatives.... It is in the title @kleineg   fxy=fyx

Comment: Well whoever it was who downvoted this.... mention the reason... and yes i am concerned about the answer to my question so feel free to point out any mistake in my question.

Comment: here would help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Requirement_of_continuity

Comment: but this is better http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m200/mixed.pdf : )

Comment: I did not downvote but I can easily guess why somebody might consider this worth downvoting. You ask about some theorem, but you did not state what theorem. (The claim $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ is definitely not true without some assumption on $f$.) So if somebody wants to know what are the assumptions in theorem you are asking about, they need to get hold of the book. Questions on this site should be self-contained.

Comment: The theorem "equality of mixed partial derivatives" is quite popular... so i thought if i would just post the name.... that would be enough... and moreover googling it can easily lead to the theorem..... but yes i could have included it in the question.... for now i dont have access to my pc so i am going to do it tomorrow @MartinSleziak

Comment: @janmarqz that is an excellent pdf. Yes, now that really gives an idea.... which is straight forward. Thankyou very much. Now as soon as you post this as answer or even just provide the pdf link in the answer, I can atleast give you a thumbsup and accept it as an answer. This, made my day.

Comment: just being constructive friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply apply the definition of a derivative and follow this link given above in the comment by Janmarqz for the [proof](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m200/mixed.pdf)